# Favorite tags not showing on custom tab in new nav

Tags: bug, tags, bookmarks, new-nav

When I create a new tab with one of my often-used tags, I don't see the other favorite tags I have lighting up.

> [image: screen shot]

I have [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) in my favorite tags too, so the third question should be highlighted. Since this is the general behavior, I am tagging this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

(Side note: it does work when refreshing the page. The initial retrieval of the page doesn't show the tags (so while in edit mode) nor the questions retrieved in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in today's release! Questions loaded in the background now highlight.

> [image]